# How do I make a hash of a directory

Tags: bash

I would like to test that a processes I am creating is making the same output each time.

I would like to do this by creating a hash of the contents of the folder. But this should not take into account the file modification times nor any .DS_Store/thumbs.db type files.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: To get a hash of the contents of each file, omitting hidden files, cd into the directory of interest and run `sha1sum *`.    To save those hashes to a file, run `sha1sum * >file.save`.

Comment: Is this like a Hash Table or a Hash Map? What does it mean to "hash content"?

Comment: Didn't you have a similar question posted on [SU] a while back and then deleted it? I thought I had an answer for you then and then suddenly you removed the question... but perhaps I'm mistaken but I'm pretty certain the OP had the same profile picture but asked about hash tables with Powershell instead. Curious if that was you and what happened there with that if you know?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to have a single hash that has takes into account all the files in a directory.

```
find . -name thumbs.db -prune -o -type f -exec cat {} \; | shasum -
```

Note I tried using tar first, but most archive formats include the timestamps, which will not give you the results you wanted.

To test this I selected a source directory and generated the sha for it as follows.  Note that I shortened the command to generate the sha for this illustration, the '-name thumbs.db -prune -o' is only used if you need to exclude some files.

```
$ find Temp\ 20060810/ -type f | wc -l
    7207
$ du -hs Temp\ 20060810/
3.6G    Temp 20060810/
$ (cd ../Temp\ 20060810/ && find . -type f -exec cat {} \;  | shasum -)
f35837a72e7c94c974ed76723ac4fcff39e62646  -
```

Then I created a few copies using different techniques:

```
$ cp -r Temp\ 20060810/ ~/tmp/TEST1
$ (cd Temp\ 20060810/ && tar -cf - .) | (mkdir ~/tmp/TEST2 && tar -C ~/tmp/TEST2 -xf - )
$ rsync -a Temp\ 20060810/ ~/tmp/TEST3/
$ cp -aL Temp\ 20060810/ ~/tmp/TEST4/
```

Finally, Compare the hash of the copies to the hash of the original:

```
$ (cd ~/tmp/TEST1 && find . -type f -exec cat {} \; | shasum -)
f35837a72e7c94c974ed76723ac4fcff39e62646  -
$ (cd ~/tmp/TEST2 && find . -type f -exec cat {} \; | shasum -)
f35837a72e7c94c974ed76723ac4fcff39e62646  -
$ (cd ~/tmp/TEST3 && find . -type f -exec cat {} \; | shasum -)
f35837a72e7c94c974ed76723ac4fcff39e62646  -
$ (cd ~/tmp/TEST4 && find . -type f -exec cat {} \; | shasum -)
f35837a72e7c94c974ed76723ac4fcff39e62646  -
```